# Locating error lines in Python Tools For Visual Studio

Tags: python, ironpython, ptvs

When working with Pydev(Eclipse) if I run source code that has an error then Pydev provides a link to locate the error line in the editor by clicking it(like any IDE does). But, PTVS doesn't seem to have such a functionality. Is there any way to locate error lines using PTVS(Python Tools For Visual Studio) like Pydev?

Comment: Are you talking about about basic, syntactic errors (e.g. indentation, missing ':') during 'compile time' or run-time issues?

Answer (score 0):

When an error occurs you should be broken into the debugger with the Exception Assistant window:  [image: debug assistant window]

That should be highlighting the current line where the error occurred.  If you want to jump around and get more context or if you've dismissed this dialog you can go to Debug->Windows->Call Stack which will show you all the frames currently on the stack.  Double clicking on any one of those frames will bring you to the location in the source code.